# MVC display UserName on layout page

Tags: model-view-controller, partial, viewbag

In my app, users can login via a barcode scan.
The scan triggers a controller action like so:

```
function scanner(value) { 
    var badge = (value.startsWith('B-') || value.startsWith('B-')); //b- of B- = badge scan
    if (badge)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Login/Login',
            data: {'badge': value},
            succes: function () {
                console.log("logged in");
            }
        });       
    }
    else return;
}
```

Controller action:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string badge)
    {
      string userName = string.Empty;
      if (badge != null)
      { 
            int oncid;
            if (Int32.TryParse(badge.Substring(2), out oncid))
            {
                Core.Employee employee =  Data.Oracle.GetEmployee(oncid.ToString());
                if (employee != null)
                {
                    userName = employee.FirstName + ' ' + employee.Name;                    
                }
            }
            else
               userName = "invalid badge";
        }
        ViewBag.UserName = userName;
        return PartialView("_Login");
    }
```

in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" height="36" width="36" class="d-inline-block align-top">&nbsp; App Name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    @*<a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>*@
                    <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"><span class="fas fa-home fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="smrButton" href="#">SMR</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("_Login")
    </div>
</nav>
```

_Login.cshtml just has @ViewBag.UserName  for now.
If i set a breakpoint here, i can see that ViewBag.UserName holds the correct value, however, nothing is displayed in my page layout. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Session instead of ViewBag. For example:

```
Session["username"] = userName;
```

And call it in the view, simple as that

Comment: Hey, i already tried Session variables. The problem remains the same : the view isn't updating. I must be missing something stupid ....

Comment: Setting the Username via javascript works, but is not very "MVC"